# Share all values clicked by the individual users with all users who accepted invitation in kotlin/android

Tags: android, design-patterns, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app in which host user sends invitation request to users and users that accept invitation are stored under one room in firestore cloud.Everything is done using firestore.

When the individual users select a value it should be stored in a sliding up view,and that should be seen by all users.I know how to create the slide up view,I want to know what logic or way can I use for this feature.

I have explained what I want to do in a rough diagram below.

Is there a way to show all values selected by individual users to all users without using firestore?

Basically its like all the moves made by users who have joined should be visible to users connected,so how to connect users and make them see the moves.I am new to kotlin so I am not sure what should I do here?

**First user diagram(selects a value which should go to the slide up view):** 
 BEFORE:

[image]

AFTER:

[image]

**Second user (should be able to see value added by first user as well as the value he adds):**

BEFORE:

[image]

AFTER:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the Observer design pattern https://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java

Comment: @Bentaye I have looked at that article and searched for many examples but dint see anything which was easy to understand for a beginner like me.Can you give me a better easy reference example in kotlin for observer pattern?And can observer pattern really help me with my above problem?